# Trigger Intellisense autocomplete using space, parenthesis, or period on Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio-code

I have been using Visual Studio Community edition for all my C# Projects. But recently I switched to Visual Studio Code for doing some work in JavaScript. The biggest thing I miss in VS Code is that option to include the autocomplete suggestion using space, parenthesis or period keys, instead, I can only include suggestion using the tab key. 
How can I change that?

Comment: Vscode is meant to be a lightweight code editor. It is not meant to be a replacement ide for Visual Studio. I'm assuming this feature is left out to keep the performance of the editor fast and efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your own keybindings for the same command.  Here is the <kbd>tab</kbd> acceptSelected Suggestion binding:

> { "key": "tab",                   "command":
>   "acceptSelectedSuggestion",
>                                        "when": "editorTextFocus && suggestWidgetVisible" },

You could add bindings for other keys.  It might be a mess or it might work for you.  In keybindings.json

Comment: above works, but the whole purpose of adding for example period is that it should add suggestion **AND** inserts period character.
How can we do that? That would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set `"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": true` in settings.json?